# PHP framework or library for DB abstraction, secure login

Tags: php, mysql, security, frameworks, authorization

I am building a site that requires a lot of MySQL inserts and lookups from different tables in a (hopefully) secure part of the site. I want to use an abstraction layer for the whole process. Should I use a PHP framework (like Zend or CakePHP) for this, or just use a simple library (like Crystal or Doctrine)?

I would also like to make sure that the DB inserts are done in a relatively secure part of the site (though not SSL). Currently, I am using the method outlined [here](http://marakana.com/blog/examples/php-implementing-secure-login-with-php-javascript-and-sessions-without-ssl.html) (MD5 encryption and random challenge string), but maybe some of the frameworks come with similar functionality that would simplify the process?

What I'm trying to implement: a table of forms filled out with DB values. If you change a value or add a new row, pressing "save" will update or insert DB rows. I'm sure this has been done before, so I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Most PHP backends have secure access to a private database.  Normally, there's little difficulty to keeping the database secure, mostly by not making it reachable directly.  That way the security of access depends on the inability for anyone to tamper with the PHP code, and not any software security scheme.

Comment: I understand, but if somebody gains access to someone's login information, they can tamper with that user's private data, no?

Comment: Sure, that's why everyone needs to keep their credentials private.  You can make it a little easier on users by providing mechanisms for undoing transactions (to correct mistakes or undo vandalism), and by educating them to take security seriously.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend [Symfony Framework](http://www.symfony-project.org/) for this. There is a great online tutorial on this at [Practical Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/).The Framework's [Form class](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10) handles most of the security for you. It also has a nice [login plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) to make the application secure.

Answer (score 0):

Unless by Data Abstraction you mean an implementation of a Data Access Patterns like ActiveRecord or Table Data Gateway or something ORMish (in both cases you should update your question accordingly then), you don't need a framework, because PHP has a DB abstraction layer with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are really asking two different questions.  One being should I use a framework (Zend, Symfony, Cake, etc) for the development of a website?  The other being whether or not to use something along the lines of an ORM (Doctrine, Propel, etc)?

The answer to the first one is a resounding "yes".  Frameworks are designed to keep you from having to reinvent the wheel for common/basic functionality.  The time you spend learning how to (correctly) use a framework will payoff greatly in the long run.  You'll eventually be much more productive that "rolling your own".  Not to mention you'll gain a community of people who have likely been through similar situations and overcome issues similar to what you will face (that in and of itself could be the best reason to use a framework).  I'm not going to suggest a particular framework since they all have strengths and weaknesses and is another topic in and of itself (however, I do use and prefer Zend Framework but don't let that influence your decision).

Concerning whether or not to use an ORM is a slightly more difficult question.  I've recently began to work with them more and in general I would recommend them but it all boils down to using the right tool for the right job.  They solve some specific problems very well, others not so much.  However, since you specifically mention security I'll quickly address that.  I don't think that a ORM inherently "increases security", however it can force you into making better decisions.  That said, bad coding and bad coding practices will result in security issues no matter what technology/framework you are using.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't many frameworks bundle their own ORM implementing the Active Record pattern?

Comment: Some (maybe most) do, but depending on the framework you aren't always tied to a particular ORM implementation.